# Magento: How to Print backend invoices like frontend as HTML?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm on Magento 1.7.0.2. How can I print invoices from backend with the same manner that frontend uses? I want it to be on HTML format not PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to print one invoice at a time from the admin order detail page

Create a custom admin module

Add a controller with the method below

```
public function printInvoiceAction()
{  

    $invoiceId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
    if ($invoiceId) {
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId);
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    } else {
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
    }


    if (isset($invoice)) {
        Mage::register('current_invoice', $invoice);
    }
    $this->loadLayout('print');
    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

Reference  printInvoiceAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/GuestController.php

Then in your custom layout.xml use `<sales_guest_printinvoice>` in /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml as your template

Then add a button with link to the following url (need to get invoice id from order) /customModule/controller/printInvoice/invoice_id/xxx

(Not tested, so let me know if you run into any issues)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom css file for printing `print.css`. And you should add "Print Button", that will call `window.print()`

Comment: The problem isn't on how to add a CSS file on the print view. The problem is how to print invoices from backend with the same manner that frontend uses? I think we will need a custom module.